# iOS audio stops playing when view controller goes backward

Tags: ios, audio

I have two view controllers in a navigation controller. I go from the first  view controller to the second, and play audio in the second view controller. However, when I press the back button to go back to the first view controller, the audio stops playing.

below is the audio playing class:

```
@interface AudioPlayer ()
@property AVAudioSession *audioSession;
@property AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property BOOL audioPlaying;
@property BOOL audioInterrupted;
@end

@implementation AudioPlayer

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self configureAudioSession];
        [self configureAudioPlayer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tryPlayMusic {
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_audioPlayer play];
    _audioPlaying = YES;
}

- (void) configureAudioSession {
    // Implicit initialization of audio session
    self.audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];

    if (setCategoryError) {
        NSLog(@"Error setting category! %ld", (long)[setCategoryError code]);
    }
}

- (void)configureAudioPlayer {
    // Create audio player with background music
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bigbigworld" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;    // Negative number means loop forever
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

because you create audioPlayer in second controller as a property. when pop, system will release the second controller, any property of second controller will be released.

If you want to continue play, you can create strong reference point from first controller to second by assign second controller as strong property of first controller.

Or you can simply play controller in first controller or navigation controller, in second when need play audio, call delegate to first controller or navigation controller. In this way, note that your delegate property is weak attribute to avoid strong reference cycle

Answer (score 0):

I guess you handle `AudioPlayer` in the second view controller.

When you back from the second view controller, the `AudioPlayer` is dealloc. So you should handle it in somewhere (not in the second view controller)